# Edit "Create local variable" template to get rid of the "final" modifier in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, templates, intellij-idea

I often use IntelliJ IDEA's <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd> hotkey to quickly generate a local variable in a method when the compiler can not find symbol.
I first write the name of the variable, then I hover over it and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd> which results in a small popup prompting me to create a local variable with the name I specified. It works fine but every time I hit this hotkey the variable gets the `final` modifier which I want to get rid of. How can I do this? I suppose it is either a Code/Live Template or a kind of Settings/Editor/Intention which I am not able to find.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your settings, go to

Editor->Code Style->Java->Code Generation (tab)->Final Modifier

And make sure that the "Make generated local variables final" is unchecked:

[image: Image showing checkbox with Make generated local variables final]

---

If that does not work, make sure that the "Declare final" checkbox that is sometimes<sup>1</sup> presented after you turn your expression into a variable is unchecked.

[image: Image of checkbox with Declare Final]

<sup>1: If it doesn't show directly, try to restart your IDE.</sup>

Comment: This didn't work. The checkbox is unchecked, but local variables are final by default.